# How to subsequently update the radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm looping throught my database items and I'm displaying styled radio buttons and here's my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(ProductsController.SelectAllProducts());

if (products.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var item in products)
    {
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#004a80"));
        RadioButton a = new RadioButton();
        a.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        a.Background = Brushes.Green;
        a.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        a.BorderBrush = mySolidColorBrush;
        a.Width = 118;
        a.Height = 70;
        a.Margin = new Thickness(5,0,0,5);
        Style style = Application.Current.Resources["MyRadioButtonAsButtonStyle"] as Style;
        a.Style = style;
        a.ApplyTemplate();
        a.Content = item.OrdinalNumber;
        Image imgControl = (Image)a.Template.FindName("img", a);
        Image imgControlWhite = (Image)a.Template.FindName("whiteImg", a);
        TextBlock text = (TextBlock)a.Template.FindName("text", a);
        a.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
            MessageBox.Show(radioButton.Content.ToString());
        };
        text.Text = item.Title;
        imgControl.Source = image;
        spProducts.Children.Add(a);
    }
}
```

On the beggining of my class I get all products from Db and I've created as many radio buttons as there are products and it looks like this:

If products.Count is 8 than we will see 8 radio buttons which are styled as buttons:

[image]

After while I would like to change background colour or title on the radio button but I would not like to refresh a whole screen so I've added `INotifyPropertyChanged` and product is list of type `Product` which looks like this:

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Attributes
    private string _ordinalNumber;
    private string _title;
    private string _description;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string OrdinalNumber
    {
        get { return _ordinalNumber; }
        set { _ordinalNumber = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("OrdinalNumber"); }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Title"); }
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Description"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And somewhere in my code in same file I've tried to modify a title:

```
var dbProduct = ProductController.Instance.GetProductByTitle(title);

var listItem = products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrdinalNumber == dbProduct.OrdinalNumber);
listItem.Title = "Test";
```

But nothing happened, I thought since `products` was source for creating radio buttons, so if I change `Title` of some item in that list it would affect radio button on screen since I'm using that `Title` prop while I'm displaying radio button text.

Any kind of help would be awesome.

Comment: Where is your binding? And why are you not doing this in xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a binding for changes to be tracked in the UI. Something like this:

Instead of -

```
text.Text = item.Title;
```

Have this -

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Title");
binding.Source = item;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(text, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, I did not know that it has to be bildings to be tracked in the UI.. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I would recommend you look into implementing the MVVM pattern and use XAML - it may have been a lot easier :)